# Will enough time pass where I'll get a fresh start here on Aviation SE?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, closed-questions, privileges

I can't see when I got a question ban nor have any idea when I will be allowed to ask again. Can I get a date or direction? I can't revise my current questions without getting more down votes or invalidating the answers. Some of them shouldn't have been asked here. Who has the power to reset me? I'll pay a fine or make a donation.

Answer (score 4):

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/376358) is said:

> ### How long do I have to wait before I can post again? What can I do to release the ban? How can I reactivate my account?
>
> Automatic bans never expire or "time out." This means that you cannot
>   simply wait for a certain amount of time. If you do not take action,
>   you will never be allowed to post again. The only way for the ban to
>   be lifted is by contributing positively to the site in other ways.
>
> Moderators cannot lift the ban.
>
> Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts! As noted above,
>   down-votes cast by the rest of the community factor into the ban - so
>   the single best thing you can do to get it lifted is to address any
>   objections raised by others. Were your past questions unclear? Did
>   they fail to show any effort on your part? Poorly worded, titled,
>   formatted, and overly long or short? Then fix them!
>
> Note the emphasis on fixing. Do not delete your posts. As explained
>   above, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) do
>   still count towards the question ban. Deleting your posts does not
>   help to lift the ban. Only fixing does! Under some conditions you can
>   see a list of your own deleted questions and answers.
>
> **If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the
>   chance to ask one new one 6 months after your last question. If that
>   question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking
>   questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.**
>
> If you are banned from asking questions, then writing a few quality
>   answers that get upvoted might enable you to ask questions again. But
>   as the internals of the filter are secret, there is no way to know for
>   sure.
>
> If you really, really think the ban is an error, then email the team
>   directly using the "contact us" link provided at the bottom of every
>   page. But note that reactivation of banned accounts is not a high
>   priority.

So you get one chance after 6 months. If I remember correctly you used alredy a few of these chances, so I cannot say if and when you'll get another one, this is completely out of our control.

It is not possible to remove the ban in any other way than the ones listed in the post I linked. Please read that post carefully.

Comment: I'll also add that well, if you actually find this community enriching, you can learn a lot, both about the subject matter *and* about what sort of questions work here by hanging out and browsing questions every so often. Amazingly, there's more to Q&A than just Q.